# Как правильно: "с льготами" или "со льготами"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

Как правильно в данном предложении: "с" или "со"?

*Как работать на онлайн-кассе с/со льготным товаром.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Грамота.ру отвечает [так](http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D1%81%D0%BE%20%D0%BB%D1%8C):

> Верно: *с льготой.* Подробнее см. в вопросе [295574](http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=295574).

> Предлог *со* употребляется: <...> 2) перед формами родительного и творительного падежа слов *лев, лёд, лён, лоб, мох, ров, рот: схватка со львом, виски со льдом*.

Почему-то ***льгота*** пока не попала в этот список.

Comment: Причём в ответе на вопрос 295574 первой же строчкой написано: "Предлог со употребляется: 1) перед словами, начинающимися с сочетаний [с, з, ш, ж + согласный]". Видимо отвечавшего смутило, что "ь" исторически гласный, но как раз слова, где она выпадает п.2, показывают, что современным языком мягкий знак гласным не воспринимается

Answer (score 3):

Интересно, что на той же "Грамоте" имеется и другая информация о предлогах **с/со**.

[Вопрос № 251490](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=251490)

> Предлог *со* фонетически закономерен перед словами, начинающимися с сочетаний [с, з, ш, ж + согласная] или с согласной [щ]: со ста, со славой, со звездой, со шкафа, со жгутом, со щами. Поэтому: со зверем, но с зайцем.
> Также предлог *со* употребляется перед формами с начальными сочетаниями [л, ль, р, м] + согласная: со лба, со мной, со льдом, со ртом; также перед сочетаниями [в] + согласная: со вторника, со всеми, со второго.

Вот еще несколько слов с сочетанием *ль + согласная*: льготник, львица, львенок, льдина, льдинка, лье, льстец, льстивость.

Посмотрела в Нацкорпусе:
[**со** льготой](https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=CjUKE9GB0L4g0LvRjNCz0L7RgtC%2B0LkqFwoICAAQChgyIAogACiWn4bKz%2BfwCEAFMgIIAToBATAB) — 3, [**с** льготой](https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=CjMKEdGBINC70YzQs9C%2B0YLQvtC5KhcKCAgAEAoYMiAKIAAoyJXlwb6R5QJABTICCAE6AQEwAQ%3D%3D) — 1;
со львом — 401, с львом (в основном с Львом) — 236;
со львенком — 1, с львенком — 2.

Погуглила:
**со** льготой — 31300, **с** льготой — 11500.

Думаю, что употребление *со льготой* удобнее для произношения.

[Как употреблять предлоги](https://spbdnevnik.ru/news/2016-09-02/rasskazhi-mne-obo-vsem--kak-upotreblyat-predlogi) (gramma.ru):

Comment: @Максим Эх, Максим, Максим! В вопросе № 295574, конечно, слова "льгота" нет (ну... невозможно ведь все слова перечислить). А вот в вопросе  № 251490 имеется **конкретное** указание: *предлог **со** употребляется перед формами с начальными сочетаниями... **ль** + согласная...* Странный Вы сделали выбор-перевыбор.